# dayGridMonth view not showing dot maker for all the days in date range event

Tags: fullcalendar, servicenow

I'm using fullcalendar in servicenow as a plugin available here, https://developer.servicenow.com/connect.do#!/share/contents/4545518_angular_calendar_widgets_fullcalendar?t=PRODUCT_DETAILS

As the initial view, I'm using dayGridMonth and set the event property display: "list-item".
It's working fine with the single-day event. but if the event is more than one day, the list-icon(color dot) only shows on the start date, not on the other days that belong to the event.

As an example event(9a) on 28th is an event of the start:2021-06-28 end: 2021-07-01, then it should show the green list icon on 29th, 30th, and 1st. but the green list-icon only shows on the start date.

Now I want to show the list-icon all the dates belong to the event date range, Please provide the solution to this.

This is the event object

```
{ "title":"9a", 
  "start":"2021-06-28T08:00:00", 
  "end":"2021-07-01T23:00:00",
  "display": "list-item"  
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be unrelated to the event data you've provided, so I'm not sure why you've provided that? Anyway  I don't think what you're asking for makes much sense from a usability perspective. Each event on the calendar has one dot and one instance of the time and description, regardless of how long the event lasts. If you repeat the info on each page it will look like a recurring event, not a single ongoing events. Unfortunately by choosing "list-item" display you've lost the formatting properties which show the bar crossing all the days.

Comment: With list-item formatting: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEeMXRd . Without list-item formatting, using default instead: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/qBrMPMN

Comment: Hi ADyson, 

Thank you for the quick reply.

I need to show the dot for the each date, that belong to the event, as the listWeek
in your sample codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ZEeMXRd, I can see the dot for every date (28, 29,30, 1) .

I need to show the same way but in the dayGridMonth view instead of listMonth view.

Comment: I've already explained why that isn't happening. Just use the default display. Listweek works a completely different way to dayGridMonth, there's not much point in comparing them. If you want to change the behaviour I've explained, you'd have to write a custom view - probably not with it, it's a lot of work.

Comment: P.s. I think the list-item format was really designed for single day events. If you think fullCalendar should change its approach then go to https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features